# popoverControllerDidDismissPopover NOT doing what I think it should

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipopovercontroller, uipopover

So, I think that when I click outside of a popover, the method `popoverControllerDidDismissPopover` should be called.  I know this isn't called when `dismissPopoverAnimated` is called.

I have a simple project that I have setup that shows `popoverControllerDidDismissPopover` just isn't called:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "PopoverViewController.h"
@interface ViewController ()
{
PopoverViewController *controller;
UIPopoverController *popoverController;
}
@end
@implementation ViewController
@synthesize button;
- (IBAction)showPopover:(UIButton *)sender
{
if ([popoverController isPopoverVisible]) {
    [popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
} else {
    CGRect popRect = CGRectMake(self.button.frame.origin.x,
                                self.button.frame.origin.y,
                                self.button.frame.size.width,
                                self.button.frame.size.height);
    [popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:popRect
                                       inView:self.view
                     permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny
                                     animated:YES];
   }
}
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
controller = [[PopoverViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PopoverViewController" bundle:nil];
popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:controller];
}
- (void)viewDidUnload
{
[super viewDidUnload];
// Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
return YES;
}


- (void)popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController {

NSLog(@"Why am I never called!!!!");

}

- (BOOL)popoverControllerShouldDismissPopover:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController
{
return true;
}

@end
```

Please tell me where I'm going wrong or how I can detect when a popover is dismissed.

The whole project is here:

https://rapidshare.com/files/3182903825/PopoverDemo.zip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never set the `delegate` for your `popoverController` to `self`.

```
_popoverController.delegate = self;
```

Comment: Will do, in a few minutes when it lets me

Answer (score 1):

You didn't set the `delegate` of your `popoverController`. Add the following code to the end of the `viewDidLoad` method:

```
popoverController.delegate = self;
```