# How to know when popover dismissed in iOS 9: popoverControllerDidDismissPopover deprecated

Tags: ios, swift

These posts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16672108/popovercontrollerdiddismisspopover-not-doing-what-i-think-it-should) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25199466/popover-popovercontrollerdiddismisspopover-not-called) discuss how to get notified when a popover gets dismissed in iOS, but according to the docs, the primary delegate functions `popoverControllerShouldDismissPopover` and `popoverControllerDidDismissPopover` are deprecated in iOS 9.

So what's the right way to get notified when a popover gets dismissed?

Comment: Duplicated question. [Look here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33468698/how-to-detect-when-a-popover-is-dismissed-in-ios-9)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use this instead

```
func popoverPresentationControllerDidDismissPopover(popoverPresentationController: UIPopoverPresentationController){

}
```

> The methods of the UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate protocol
>   let you customize the behavior of a popover-based presentation. A
>   popover presentation controller notifies your delegate at appropriate
>   points during the presentation process. You can use the delegate
>   methods to customize this process and respond to changes dynamically.

[Apple reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate_protocol/)

Comment: yup SO won't allow accepting yet ... you were too fast :)